# A trigger to set an id for a parent row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm sure I'm doing several things wrong here. Let me set up the goal.

I have a simple table with columns like:

```
-----------------------------------------
id | name   | code | parentCode | parentId
1  | locOne | loc1 |            | 
2  | locTwo | loc2 | loc1       | (grab value of 1)
3  | locThr | loc3 | loc2       | (grab value of 2)
```

I would like to import name, code and parentCode from a csv file. The id would be auto-entered

Then I was hoping it is possible to write a trigger, which would enter the auto-entered id into the parentId column, grabbing the id from where parentCode=code.

1) FIRST QUESTION -- is this possible?

I'm using SequelPro, and tried this as a trigger on Update:

```
INSERT INTO location (parentId)
SELECT id
FROM location
WHERE parentCode=code
```

Which threw the error:

> Unable to write row

MySQL said:

> Can't update table 'location' in stored function/trigger because it is
>   already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

2) SECOND QUESTION -- how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can't issue DML statements on a table on which you have defined your trigger.
But what you can do is you can use `BEFORE` trigger to change values that are being inserted or updated.

Now assuming that your table's schema looks something like

```
CREATE TABLE location
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  name varchar(128), 
  code varchar(128), 
  parentCode varchar(128), 
  parentId int
)
```

Your trigger might look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_location
BEFORE INSERT ON location
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.parentId = (SELECT id 
                        FROM location 
                       WHERE code = NEW.parentCode);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44b20/1)** demo

---

Now assuming that your CSV file look like

```
name,code,parentCode 
"locOne","loc1",
"locTwo","loc2","loc1"
"locThr","loc3","loc2"
```

you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to bulk load your data

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv'
INTO TABLE location
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or `\r\n` if it's Windows
IGNORE 1 LINES -- use this if your file contains a header line
(name, code, parentcode);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. This is a very clear explanation and perfectly solves the issue. And, I wasn't aware of SQLFiddle, so one more learning resource. I really appreciate the thoughtful answer. I have a very denormalized reporting table. This method of setting values before insert will allow me to keep a lot of things in sync more easily. Allowing fast queries on the keys without actually defining the relationship.

Comment: @manisha You're quite welcome. I'm glad I could help :) Good luck.